# MySQL - Sum and Count

Tags: mysql

I would like to calculate the average of sum (percentage value) by each services divided by all the server for the specific service between start and stop date, must also ignore the value "nil"

```
start_date stop_date conn ftp http imap pop3 smtp ssh

2013-11-28 2013-12-05 100  100 99.89 99.89 99.89 100 100
```

**Table**

```
id   timestamp            server               service  start_date       stop_date        percentage 

 1  2013-12-05 11:46:57  a.martin.sg     conn     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
 2  2013-12-05 11:46:57  a.martin.sg     ftp      2013-11-28   2013-12-05  100        
 3  2013-12-05 11:46:57  a.martin.sg     http     2013-11-28   2013-12-05  100        
 4  2013-12-05 11:46:57  a.martin.sg     imap     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  nil        
 5  2013-12-05 11:46:57  a.martin.sg     pop3     2013-11-28   2013-12-05  100        
 6  2013-12-05 11:46:57  a.martin.sg     smtp     2013-11-28   2013-12-05  100        
 7  2013-12-05 11:46:57  a.martin.sg     ssh      2013-11-28   2013-12-05  100        
 8  2013-12-05 11:46:57  b.martin.sg   conn     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
 9  2013-12-05 11:46:57  b.martin.sg   ftp      2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
10  2013-12-05 11:46:57  b.martin.sg   http     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  99.95      
11  2013-12-05 11:46:57  b.martin.sg   imap     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  nil        
12  2013-12-05 11:46:57  b.martin.sg   pop3     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  99.47      
13  2013-12-05 11:46:57  b.martin.sg   smtp     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  99.19      
14  2013-12-05 11:46:57  b.martin.sg   ssh      2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
15  2013-12-05 11:46:57  c.martin.sg   conn     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
16  2013-12-05 11:46:57  c.martin.sg   ftp      2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
17  2013-12-05 11:46:57  c.martin.sg   http     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
18  2013-12-05 11:46:57  c.martin.sg   imap     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  nil        
19  2013-12-05 11:46:57  c.martin.sg   pop3     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
20  2013-12-05 11:46:57  c.martin.sg   smtp     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
21  2013-12-05 11:46:57  c.martin.sg   ssh      2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
22  2013-12-05 11:46:57  d.martin.sg     conn     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
23  2013-12-05 11:46:57  d.martin.sg     ftp      2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100        
24  2013-12-05 11:46:57  d.martin.sg     http     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  99.89        
25  2013-12-05 11:46:57  d.martin.sg     imap     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  nil        
26  2013-12-05 11:46:57  d.martin.sg     pop3     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  99.89      
27  2013-12-05 11:46:57  d.martin.sg     smtp     2013-11-28  2013-12-05  99.78      
28  2013-12-05 11:46:57  d.martin.sg     ssh      2013-11-28  2013-12-05  100
```

Current attempt:

```
SELECT   service,
         SUM(IF(service = 'http', percentage, 0)) AS 'http',
         SUM(percentage) AS Total
FROM     virtualunix
WHERE    start = '2013-11-28'
GROUP BY service;
```

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| service | http    | Total   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| conn    |       0 | 3392.39 |
| ftp     |       0 | 2699.68 |
| http    | 3399.34 | 3399.34 |
| imap    |       0 |     900 |
| pop3    |       0 | 2897.09 |
| smtp    |       0 | 2897.01 |
| ssh     |       0 | 3399.95 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: You need to show an actual attempt at trying to solve this problem.

Comment: mysql> select
    -> service,
    -> SUM(IF(service = 'http', percentage, 0)) AS 'http',
    -> -- snip
    -> SUM(percentage) AS Total
    -> FROM
    -> virtualunix
    -> WHERE
    -> start = '2013-11-28'
    -> GROUP BY
    -> service;
+---------+---------+---------+
| service | http    | Total   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| conn    |       0 | 3392.39 |
| ftp     |       0 | 2699.68 |
| http    | 3399.34 | 3399.34 |
| imap    |       0 |     900 |
| pop3    |       0 | 2897.09 |
| smtp    |       0 | 2897.01 |
| ssh     |       0 | 3399.95 |
+---------+---------+---------+

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood, don't you simply want to use [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) instead of [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)?

```
SELECT   service, AVG(percentage)
FROM     virtualunix
WHERE    start_date = '2013-11-28'
GROUP BY service
```

Comment: can we skip the value "nil"? so it won't get divided?

Comment: The numbers doesnt seem right. service AVG(percentage)
conn    99.7761764705882
ftp     79.4023529411765
http    99.9805882352941
imap    26.4705882352941
pop3    85.2085294117647
smtp    85.2061764705882
ssh     99.9985294117647

Comment: @user1204671: You really *ought* to be using a [numeric data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-types.html), with [`NULL` values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/null-values.html) where data is missing/unknown.  However, as things stand, you can add `AND percentage <> 'nil'` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: example, i would like to sum "conn" then divide the total by the numbers of servers that has the service "conn". Also i would like to skip the value "nil" from the calculation